# Oracle Database 11g: How to enable/create a user?

Tags: oracle

I just downloaded the Oracle Database 11g and I can't select,create,update or do anything. Every command that I entered and run only results to "ORA-01435: user does not exist"

What are the things that i need to do in order to enable creating and running some commands?

Here is a picture of ORA-01435: user does not exist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please look at right upper corner `SCHEMA:XS$NULL`:

[image]

> From [Securing Oracle Database User Accounts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm)
>
> **XS$NULL**
>
> An internal account that represents the absence of a user in a session. Because XS$NULL is not a user, this account can only be accessed by the Oracle Database instance. XS$NULL has no privileges and no one can authenticate as XS$NULL, nor can authentication credentials ever be assigned to XS$NULL.
>
> **Expired and locked**

You need to change it to some specific schema.